# How to use a routing url in the anchor tag helper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am using Razor Pages and have a file "Author.cshtml" inside a catalog /Pages/Author/ with the following content:

```
@page "/Author"
@model MyApplication.Web.Pages.Author.AuthorModel

Lorem ipsum
```

I set routing as "/Author".
The following link doesn't work:

```
<a asp-page="/Author">Author</a>
```

I need to write:

```
<a asp-page="/Author/Author">Author</a>
```

But I want to use: "/Author", not "/Author/Author" in the anchor tag helper, what should I do?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need `"/Author"` after `@page`. Or the problem is that the Author.cshtml file is inside a folder called Author

Comment: Any reason why you're using the server processing `asp-page` property when you could just use `href`?

Comment: @gunr2171 - you're right - I can use "href" thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<a href="" @onclick="NavigatetoNextComponent">Click here</a>  
  
@code {  
    void NavigatetoNextComponent()  
    {  
         NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Author", true);
    }  
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) will help people understand the reasons for your code suggestion.